# Is there significance in the order of Haskell function parameters?

Tags: haskell

I've been learning Haskell and I noticed that many of the built in functions accept parameters in an order counter intuitive to what I would expect.  For example:

```
replicate :: Int -> a -> [a]
```

If I want to replicate 7 twice, I would write `replicate 2 7`.  But when read out loud in English, the function call feels like it is saying "Replicate 2, 7 times". If I would have written the function myself, I would have swapped the first and second arguments so that `replicate 7 2` would read "replicate 7, 2 times".

Some other examples appeared when I was going through [99 Haskell Problems](https://wiki.haskell.org/H-99:_Ninety-Nine_Haskell_Problems). I had to write a function:

```
dropEvery :: [a] -> Int -> [a]`
```

It takes a list as its first argument and an `Int` as its second. Intuitively, I would have written the header as `dropEvery :: Int -> [a] -> [a]` so that `dropEvery 3 [1..100]` would read as: "drop every third element in the list `[1..100]`.  But in the question's example, it would look like: `dropEvery [1..100] 3`.

I've also seen this with other functions that I cannot find right now. Is it common to write functions in such a way due to a practical reason or is this all just in my head?

Comment: Do not use 99 Haskell problems as an indication of Haskell idiom! They're (often badly) translated versions of Lisp problems translated from Prolog. They ask for arguments in the wrong order all the time, and ask for things that just seem silly in a typed language.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

One of the reasons functions are written this way is because their curried forms turn out to be useful.

For example, consider the functions `map` and `filter`:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
filter :: (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]
```

If I wanted to keep the even numbers in a list and then divide them by 2, I could write:

```
myfunc :: [Int] -> [Int]
myfunc as = map (`div` 2) (filter even as)
```

which may also be written this way:

```
myfunc = map (`div` 2) . filter even
         \___ 2 ____/    \___ 1 ___/
```

Envision this as a pipeline going from right to left:

- first we keep the even numbers (step 1)
- then we divide each number by 2 (step 2)

The `.` operator at as a way of joining pipeline segments together - much like how the `|` operator works in the Unix shell.

This is all possible because the list argument for `map` and `filter` are the last parameters to those functions.

If you write your `dropEvery` with this signature:

```
dropEvery :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
```

then we can include it in one of these pipelines, e.g.:

```
myfunc2 = dropEvery 3 . map (`div` 2) . filter even
```

Answer (score 18):

It's common practice in Haskell to order function parameters so that parameters which "configure" an operation come first, and the "main thing being operated on" comes last. This is often counter intuitive coming from other languages, since it tends to mean you end up passing the "least important" information first. It's especially jarring coming from OO where the "main" argument is usually the object on which the method is being invoked, occurring so early in in the call that it's out of the parameter list entirely!

There's a method to our madness though. The reason we do this is that partial application (through currying) is so easy and so widely used in Haskell. Say I have a functions like `foo :: Some -> Config -> Parameters -> DataStrucutre -> DataStructure` and `bar :: Differnt -> Config -> DataStructure -> DataStructure`. When you're not used to higher-order thinking you just see these as things you call to transform a data structure. But you can *also* use either of them as a factory for "DataStructure transformers": functions of the type `DataStructure -> DataStructure`.

It's very likely that there are *other* operations that are configured *by* such `DataStructure -> DataStructure` functions; at the very least there's `fmap` for turning transformers of DataStructures into transformers of functors of DataStructures (lists, Maybes, IOs, etc).

We can take this a bit further sometimes too. Consider `foo :: Some -> Config -> Parameters -> DataStructure -> DataStructure` again.  If I expect that callers of `foo` will often call it many times with the same `Some` and `Config`, but varying `Parameters`, then even-more-partial applications become useful.

Of course, even if the parameters are in the "wrong" order for my partial application I can still do it, using combinators like `flip` and/or creating wrapper functions/lambdas. But this results in a lot of "noise" in my code, meaning that a reader has to be able to puzzle out what is the "important" thing being done and what's just adapting interfaces.

So the basic theory is for a function writer to try to anticipate the usage patterns of the function, and list its arguments in order from "most stable" to "least stable". This isn't the *only* consideration of course, and often there are conflicting patterns and no clear "best" order.

But "the order the parameters would be listed in an English sentence describing the function call" would not be something I would give much weight to in designing a function (and not in other languages either). Haskell code just does not read like English (nor does code in most other programming languages), and trying to make it closer in a few cases doesn't really help.

For your specific examples:

1. For `replicate`, it seems to me like the `a` parameter is the "main" argument, so I would put it last, as the standard library does. There's not a lot in it though; it doesn't seem *very* much more useful to choose the number of replications first and have an `a -> [a]` function than it would be to choose the replicated element first and have an `Int -> [a]` function.
2. `dropEvery` indeed seems to take it's arguments in a wonky order, but not because we say in English "drop every Nth element in a list". Functions that take a data structure and return a "modified version of the same structure" should almost always take the data structure as their last argument, with the parameters that configure the "modification" coming first.

Comment: By usage patterns `div`, `mod`, and `(!!)` seem to have their parameters in the wrong order

Comment: @luqui Yes, but there are other reasons for their parameter order. `div` and `mod` are too related to existing symbology from mathematics (and other programming languages) to want to reverse the order. Plus with infix operator it's pretty much as easy to leave out the first argument as the second.

Answer (score 3):

To add to the other answers, there's also often an incentive to make the last argument be the one whose construction is likely to be most complicated and/or to be a lambda abstraction. This way one can write

```
f some little bits $
  big honking calculation
  over several lines
```

rather than having the big calculation surrounded by parentheses and a few little arguments trailing off at the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to flip arguments, just use `flip` function from Prelude

```
replicate' = flip replicate

> :t replicate'
replicate' :: a -> Int -> [a]
```