# Why function is the first argument in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I started to learn Haskell. I'm curious about why in Haskell the function is taken as the first argument for the higher order functions for lists. For example here is a definition of `map`:

```
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]
```

It means that I can use it either in prefix or operator form like that:

```
-- yields [3,5,7]
map (+ 2) [1,3,5]
-- we can chain like that
filter (< 4) (map (+ 2) [1,3,5])

-- or in operator form 
(+ 2) `map` [1,3,5]
(< 4) `filter` ((+ 2) `map` [1,3,5])
```

In Scala the same can be written as follows:

```
List(1,3,5) map (_ + 2)
// we can chain as follows:
List(1,3,5) map (_ + 2) filter (_ < 4)
```

So the order is reversed and we take the function as the second argument. What is the reason on arguments ordering in Haskell?

Comment: `squareList = map (**2)`. You can "upgrade" a function to work on lists. What's not convenient about that?

Comment: `map` is also `fmap`. `fmap` is usually thought of as something that "upgrades" functions to work with special types (Functors).

Comment: @MateenUlhaq I don't want to argue about what is convenient or not. I'm curious about the reasoning behind such a decision, that's all. In other languages, the decision is different, which I just get used to.

Comment: @IzbassarTolegen The reasoning *is*  that it's very convenient.

Comment: @IzbassarTolegen In fact, for many functions in Haskell, the _only_ reason for their argument order is convenience. For more details on argument order, see [HaskellWiki](https://wiki.haskell.org/Parameter_order), [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31736467/is-there-significance-in-the-order-of-haskell-function-parameters), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5863128/ordering-of-parameters-to-make-use-of-currying).

Comment: In Scala the function isn't the second argument to `map` - it's the only argument to `map`. The function couldn't be on the left of the method name because then you'd be calling `map` on the function object, not on the list, and functions don't have a method named `map`.

Comment: for the function `(>>=)`, a function is its *second* argument, not first. Also for the function `(&)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is just a convention. This order is in most cases more useful than the opposite, because usually from `Data.List` library you would rather expect utilities that will allow you to "transform given list" than "describe how to transform some fixed list".

Check this case:

```
f :: [Int] -> [Int]
f = map (+1)
```

Here `f` Is a function that increments all elements of any `Int` list. It could be called `incrAll` and it would sound more flexible than

```
g :: (Int -> a) -> [a]
g f = map f [1,2,3]
```

that is fixed to work on this particular `[1,2,3]` list. Of course, it may find some usage but it is less likely in general. `f` after single application is still a function that "works on lists".

As I know Scala you may write something like `f = _.map(incr)` which is way nicer than (assuming `flipmap = flip map`) `\l -> flipmap l incr` or `flip flipmap incr`, but unfortunately Haskell does not support this kind of sugar. Next thing is that in Scala `map` has just one argument and it "belongs" to some list, so the order is quite similar to Haskell – the difference is in the philosophy of objective and functional approaches.